# Direct-Path INSERT query generates ORA-00918 error

Tags: oracle, ora-00918, direct-path

can you please explain why the error ORA-00918 is generated while executing this query

```
INSERT INTO CLG_TEST_2 (CLG_TEST_2.record_id, CLG_TEST_2.chain_id, 

CLG_TEST_2.chain_n, 
CLG_TEST_2.contact_info)

select * from (

SELECT 1, 1, 0, '2222' from dual UNION ALL

SELECT 2, 2, 0, '4444' from dual UNION ALL

SELECT 3, 3, 0, '6666' from dual

)
```

Error at line 1
ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined

Script Terminated on line 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is in the fact that you are using a `select *` over a query without giving aliases to the columns; this will work:

```
INSERT INTO CLG_TEST_2 (CLG_TEST_2.record_id,
                        CLG_TEST_2.chain_id,
                        CLG_TEST_2.chain_n,
                        CLG_TEST_2.contact_info)
select *
from (
        SELECT 1 a, 1 b, 0 c, '2222' d from dual UNION ALL
        SELECT 2  , 2  , 0  , '4444'   from dual UNION ALL
        SELECT 3  , 3  , 0  , '6666'   from dual
     )
```

However, you can simplify your code:

```
INSERT INTO CLG_TEST_2 (record_id, chain_id, chain_n, contact_info)
    SELECT 1, 1, 0, '2222' from dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, 2, 0, '4444' from dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 3, 3, 0, '6666' from dual
```

Something more about the reason of the error.

Your code:

```
SQL> INSERT INTO CLG_TEST_2 (
  2      CLG_TEST_2.record_id,
  3      CLG_TEST_2.chain_id,
  4      CLG_TEST_2.chain_n,
  5      CLG_TEST_2.contact_info)
  6  select * from (
  7      SELECT 1, 1, 0, '2222' from dual UNION ALL
  8      SELECT 2, 2, 0, '4444' from dual UNION ALL
  9      SELECT 3, 3, 0, '6666' from dual
 10  );
select * from (
       *
ERROR at line 6:
ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined
```

Slightly different:

```
SQL> INSERT INTO CLG_TEST_2 (
  2      CLG_TEST_2.record_id,
  3      CLG_TEST_2.chain_id,
  4      CLG_TEST_2.chain_n,
  5      CLG_TEST_2.contact_info)
  6  select * from (
  7      SELECT 1, 2, 0, '2222' from dual UNION ALL
  8      SELECT 2, 2, 0, '4444' from dual UNION ALL
  9      SELECT 3, 3, 0, '6666' from dual
 10  );

3 rows created.
```

What's different?

In the first row, I changed

```
SELECT 1, 1, 0, '2222' --> SELECT 1, 2, 0, '2222'
          ^                          ^
```

The reason:

```
SQL> SELECT 1, 2, 0, '2222' from dual UNION ALL
  2  SELECT 2, 2, 0, '4444' from dual UNION ALL
  3  SELECT 3, 3, 0, '6666' from dual;

         1          2          0 '222
---------- ---------- ---------- ----
         1          2          0 2222
         2          2          0 4444
         3          3          0 6666

SQL> SELECT 1, 1, 0, '2222' from dual UNION ALL
  2  SELECT 2, 2, 0, '4444' from dual UNION ALL
  3  SELECT 3, 3, 0, '6666' from dual;

         1          1          0 '222
---------- ---------- ---------- ----
         1          1          0 2222
         2          2          0 4444
         3          3          0 6666

SQL>
```

Here you have two columns with the same alias `'1'`, and this is confusing for the external `select *`.

Also, a [direct-path insert](http://docs.oracle.com/database/122/ADMIN/managing-tables.htm#GUID-BC07CE7E-92E3-4C2D-BA31-88659D10BD30) is something different

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any "Direct-Path" insert. Anyway, try this one

```
INSERT INTO CLG_TEST_2 (CLG_TEST_2.record_id, CLG_TEST_2.chain_id,     
   CLG_TEST_2.chain_n, 
   CLG_TEST_2.contact_info)    
SELECT 1, 1, 0, '2222' from dual UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 2, 0, '4444' from dual UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 3, 0, '6666' from dual
```

btw, why do you use string from numbers?